# Supabase auth causing NextJS app to constantly re-render

Tags: reactjs, authentication, next.js, supabase

I'm trying to set up Supabase auth with a NextJS app that uses the page directory (not app router). I've set it up as per the tutorial, but the way I've set it up, on the first login into the app, the app gets into a refresh loop. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with the way I'm trying to use sessions, but I'm not entirely sure.

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

app.tsx

```
const App = ({
  Component,
  pageProps,
}: AppProps<{ initialSession: Session }>) => {
  const [supabase] = useState(() => createPagesBrowserClient());

  return (
    <SessionContextProvider
      supabaseClient={supabase}
      initialSession={pageProps.initialSession}
    >
      <Head>
        <link
          rel="apple-touch-icon"
          sizes="180x180"
          href="/apple-touch-icon.png"
        />
        <link rel="icon" href="/icons/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <NextSeo
        title={siteTitle}
        description={siteDescription}
        openGraph={{
          title: siteTitle,
          description: siteDescription,
        }}
      />
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </SessionContextProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

callback.ts

```
import { createPagesServerClient } from '@supabase/auth-helpers-nextjs'

const handler = async (req, res) => {
  const { code } = req.query

  if (code) {
    const supabase = createPagesServerClient({ req, res })
    await supabase.auth.exchangeCodeForSession(String(code))
  }

  res.redirect('/')
}

export default handler
```

MainContent.tsx

```
export const MainContent = ({ override }: { override?: any }) => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState<Array<Messages>>([]);
  const [currentConversation, setCurrentConversation] = useStore((state) => [
    state.currentConversation,
    state.setCurrentConversation,
  ]);
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useStore((state) => [
    state.currentUser,
    state.setCurrentUser,
  ]);

  const [sentMessages, setSentMessages] = useState(0);

  const session = useSession();

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUserID = async () => {
      const auth_id = session.user.id;
      const userIDResponse = await axios.get("api/load-auth-user-id", {
        params: { auth_id: auth_id },
      });
      setCurrentUser(userIDResponse.data);
    };
    if (session) getUserID();
  }, [session]);

  return (
    <div
      style={override}
      className="flex flex-row items-start relative w-full h-full"
    >
      <Sidebar />
      <div className="flex flex-col items-start flex-1 bg-white h-full">
        <CurrentRecipient />
        <div className="flex flex-col justify-end items-center p-3 relative w-full gap-2 overflow-y-scroll h-3/4">
          {messages &&
            messages.map(
              (message, i) =>
                message.from_id &&
                message.text && (
                  <MessageWrapper
                    from={message.from_id}
                    message={message.text}
                    key={i}
                  />
                )
            )}
        </div>
        <CurrentMessage setSentMessages={setSentMessages} messages={messages} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Call of Auth UI component

```
<Auth
  supabaseClient={supabase}
  appearance={{ theme: ThemeSupa }}
  redirectTo="http://localhost:3000/api/auth/callback"
  providers={["google"]}
/>
```

At first I thought that the useEffect within MainContent was repeatedly firing, but trying to console.log/profile that was ineffective since the whole page was actually re-rendering (and console/profiler results aren't stored between full page re-renders).